# Can one get the type that a specific attribute is decorating

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes

Say I have a situation like so:

```
[MyAttribute]
public class MyClass
{

}

[AttributeUssage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyAttribute
{
    public MyAttribute(String a_strName)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there anyway that within constructor of `MyAttribute` I can know that the attribute is attached to `MyClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not - attributes don't "know" what they're applied to.